# Get all the Jobs,Batch etc related to particular user

Tags: administration

There is a user in my org and he is scheduling some scheduler, batch apex etc everything under his user name. Suppose if that user becomes inactive I want to find out what ever may be things he is the owner of just with some simple SOQL query or any configuration. So that I can find in a single place of all the Scheduler, Flows, Builder etc he owns

Answer (score 1):

You can use the page [Scheduled Jobs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_monitoring_jobs.htm&type=5) to Monitor the apex jobs or Report Running notification which are all scheduled in your org.

In SOQL, You can use this [CRON Trigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_crontrigger.htm) object to query the scheduled jobs which will show current executed time and next schedule fire time also.

Thanks.